# Is there a mistake in Zagier's "Hyperbolic manifolds and special values of Dedekind zeta-functions"?

Tags: nt.number-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, number-fields, geodesics, quaternions

I am having troubles  with Don Zagier's "Hyperbolic manifolds and special values of Dedekind zeta-functions", available at [this link](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.1007/BF01388964/fulltext.pdf), and I think there might be a mistake. In particular the problem is in the proof of Theorem 1 (§2). In this proof we have a quaternion **division** algebra $B/K$ where $K$ is a number field with **just one complex place**. $B$ is ramified at all real places (i.e. $B\otimes_K \mathbb{R}\simeq \mathbb{H}$ for al real places) and $K_1$ is a quadratic field extension of $K$ such that $B$ splits on $K_1$ (i.e. $B\otimes_K K_1\simeq M(2,K_1)$).

At the beginning of the last paragraph of page 288 Zagier says:
"Let, then, $\Delta\subset \mathcal{H}^3$ be a tetrahedron with vertices $P_i=(z_i,r_i)\in K_1\times (K_1\cap \mathbb{R})_+^*\subset \mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{R}_+^*$ $(i=0,1,2,3)$. The geodesic through $P_0$ and $P_1$, continued in the direction from $P_0$ to $P_1$, meets the ideal boundary $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})=\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ of $\mathcal{H}^3$ in a point of $\mathbb{P}^1(K_1)$ [...]".
Here $\mathcal{H}^3$ is the half-upper space model for the 3-dimensional hyperbolic space.

My question is: **why does the geodesic meets the boundary in $\mathbb{P}^1(K_1)=K_1\cup\{\infty\}$?**

I tried to do some obvious calculations and I considered a semicircle going from $P_0$ to $P_1$ and then to the boundary. The coordinates for the centre $C$ of the semicircle are
$$C=\left(z_0+(z_1-z_0)\cdot\left[\frac{r_1^2-r_0^2}{2|z_1-z_0|^2}+\frac{1}{2}\right],0\right).$$
The intersections of the geodesic with $\mathbb{C}\times\{0\}$ are
$$\left( z_0+(z_1-z_0)\cdot\left[\frac{r_1^2-r_0^2}{2|z_1-z_0|^2}+\frac{1}{2}\right] \pm (z_1-z_0)\sqrt{\frac{r_0^2}{|z_1-z_0|^2}+\left(  \frac{r_1^2-r_0^2}{2|z_1-z_0|^2}+\frac{1}{2} \right)^2},0  \right)=\\
\left( z_0+(z_1-z_0)\cdot\left[\frac{r_1^2-r_0^2}{2|z_1-z_0|^2}+\frac{1}{2}\pm \sqrt{\frac{r_0^2}{|z_1-z_0|^2}+\left(  \frac{r_1^2-r_0^2}{2|z_1-z_0|^2}+\frac{1}{2} \right)^2}  \right],0 \right).
$$

So, if Zagier is right, these two points should be in $K_1\times \{0\}$ and this means that
$$\left[\frac{r_1^2-r_0^2}{2|z_1-z_0|^2}+\frac{1}{2}\pm \sqrt{\frac{r_0^2}{|z_1-z_0|^2}+\left(  \frac{r_1^2-r_0^2}{2|z_1-z_0|^2}+\frac{1}{2} \right)^2}  \right]\in K_1$$

but $K_1$ is not supposed to be closed under complex conjugation and, even if we make this hypothesis, how could we know that those numbers are in $K_1$?

For these reasons I think there is a lack in the proof (or a mistake!). Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you should ask it directly to professor Zagier at  
Max-Planck-Institut für Mathematik.

Comment: @JorgeZuniga I sent him an email more then a week ago, but he hasn't replied yet.

Comment: @BernyPiffaro-Be patient. He may be checking the details of the proof. He is likely also to be very busy. Let us know what he says if he replies.

Comment: @ChrisLeary: Certainly when emailing an author about a paper one should “be patient” in the sense of not hassling them or getting indignant over a slow reply — as you say, there are many reasons an author may take a long time. But for exactly that reason, it’s very reasonable to take the question to a wider forum in the meantime.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine- Absolutely.

Comment: Slight simplification: $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb C)$ acts on the upper halfspace like this: the transformation induced by $\binom{a\ b}{c\ d}$ sends $(z,r)$ to$$\left(-\frac{\overline{z+d/c}}{c^2\left(|z+d/c|^2+r^2\right)}+\frac ac,\frac r{|c|^2\left(|z+d/c|^2+r^2\right)}\right)$$(see e. g. https://assets.cambridge.org/97811071/16740/excerpt/9781107116740_excerpt.pdf on page 6). We are looking for such transformation which has the same $z$ parts for $(z_0,r_0)$ and $(z_1,r_1)$. This then boils down to$$\bar z_0+\frac{r_0^2}{z_0+d/c}=\bar z_1+\frac{r_1^2}{z_1+d/c}$$

Comment: Crossposted at MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4752847/11323

Comment: @BernyPiffaro Generally simultaneous crossposting is frowned upon, as it may waste some effort.  Maybe delete one of these posts, and if you don't get an answer in a few days, try the other site?

Comment: @Kimball I know, you are right, but I am a student and I have to submit a relation about that theorem in about 2 weeks, so I need at least a partial answer as soon as possible.